# Is it possible to get contents of iframe in selenium webdriver python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, iframe, selenium-webdriver

In web testing, I plan to get contents of iframe(/htme/body/p), is it possible?

I use this method to set contents of iframe:

```
driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[contains(@title,'ALT')]"))
driver.switch_to_active_element()
time.sleep(1)
driver.execute_script(("document.body.innerHTML = '%s'" % recurWorkflowTestData["inputEditor"][inputNotes]))

time.sleep(1)
driver.switch_to_default_content()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To follow the same logic, you can get the `document.body.innerHTML` back:

```
source = driver.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML;")
print(source)
```