# Using selenium webdriver python to retrieve SVG text element

Tags: python, html, css, svg, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use selenium webdriver (Firefox) to get information about college courses from a website where we can see course reviews .... I can get the webdriver to successfully log into the website and reach the course info page, but once I am there I can't access the text element for the overall course rating.

Here is what the page looks like:

Course Ratings Chart:

[image: Course Ratings Chart]

And this is what the text element HTML code looks like:

```
<text style="text-anchor: middle; font: 12px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; 
opacity: 1;" x="438.00500259399416" y="131.25" text-anchor="middle" 
font="10px &quot;Arial&quot;" stroke="none" fill="#3c4c30" font-size="12px" 
font-family="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif" font-style="normal" font-
weight="normal" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" opacity="1"><tspan 
dy="4">3.00</tspan></text>
```

And the svg code:

```
<svg height="200" version="1.1" width="600" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="overflow: hidden; position: 
relative; left: -0.5px; top: -0.866669px;"><rect x="0" y="0" width="600" 
height="200" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#ffffff" 
style="stroke-linejoin: round; stroke-linecap: square; stroke-opacity: 1; 
fill-opacity: 1;" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-
width="1" stroke-opacity="1" fill-opacity="1"></rect>
.......</svg>
```

First I tried identifying the element by it's CSS selector (#chart > svg:nth-child(1) > text:nth-child(107)) but I got a nosuchelement exception.

I think the next option is to find the element by XPath but I'm not sure how to identify the "3.00"  element because it doesn't have a specific ID or class name.

Parent element1:
 (bar and text for Papers/Problem Sets)
-Papers/Psets label:

```
<text style="text-anchor: middle; font: 12px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;" 
x="0" y="0" text-anchor="middle" font="10px &quot;Arial&quot;" stroke="none" 
fill="#3c4c30" font-size="12px" font-family="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif" 
font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" 
transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,128,102.0833)"><tspan dy="4">Papers, Reports, 
Problem Sets, Examinations</tspan></text>
```

Paper/Psets bar:

```
<rect x="262.03334045410156" y="96.00694444444444" width="216.0105950756073" 
height="12.152777777777777" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#ffffff" 
stroke="#ffffff" style="stroke-linejoin: round; stroke-linecap: square; 
stroke-opacity: 0; opacity: 1; fill-opacity: 0;" stroke-linejoin="round" 
stroke-linecap="square" stroke-width="0" stroke-opacity="0" opacity="1" 
fill-opacity="0"></rect>
```

Number rating for papers/ psets:

```
<text style="text-anchor: middle; font: 12px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; 
opacity: 1;" x="458.2356021327972" y="102.08333333333333" text-
anchor="middle" font="10px &quot;Arial&quot;" stroke="none" fill="#3c4c30" 
font-size="12px" font-family="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif" font-
style="normal" font-weight="normal" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" 
opacity="1"><tspan dy="3.999997456868485">3.31</tspan></text>
```

Parent element 2 (Feedback for other students bar)

Feedback text label:

```
<text style="text-anchor: middle; font: 12px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;" 
x="0" y="0" text-anchor="middle" font="10px &quot;Arial&quot;" stroke="none" 
fill="#3c4c30" font-size="12px" font-family="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif" 
font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" 
transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,175.3333,160.4167)"><tspan dy="4">Feedback for 
other students</tspan></text>
```

Bar for feedback:

```
<rect x="262.03334045410156" y="154.34027777777777" 
width="232.3255947036743" height="12.152777777777777" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" 
fill="#ffffff" stroke="#ffffff" style="stroke-linejoin: round; stroke-
linecap: square; stroke-opacity: 0; opacity: 1; fill-opacity: 0;" stroke-
linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-width="0" stroke-opacity="0" 
opacity="1" fill-opacity="0"></rect>
```

Feedback rating text:

```
<text style="text-anchor: middle; font: 12px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; 
opacity: 1;" x="474.55060176086425" y="160.41666666666666" text-
anchor="middle" font="10px &quot;Arial&quot;" stroke="none" fill="#3c4c30" 
font-size="12px" font-family="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif" font-
style="normal" font-weight="normal" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" 
opacity="1"><tspan dy="3.9999949137369697">3.56</tspan></text>
```

Here is the entire HTML code for the body of the website from page_source:

(https://pastebin.com/zpd4iF05)

And for the python code I attempted to use to find the element:

(https://pastebin.com/aW40P86u)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to get the html from the iframe. See the answer here:
[Is it possible to get contents of iframe in selenium webdriver python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32981567/is-it-possible-to-get-contents-of-iframe-in-selenium-webdriver-python)

Once you have the code from iframe set to the driver, here's the full code to get the necessary info:

```
tspans = driver.find_element_by_id('chart').find_elements_by_tag_name("tspan")
values = map(lambda x: x.get_attribute('innerHTML'), tspans)
length = len(values)
scores = {
"Lectures": values[length-2],
"Precepts": values[length-3],
"Readings": values[length-4],
"Papers, Reports, Problem Sets, Examinations": values[length-5],
"Overall Quality of the Course": values[length-6],
"Feedback for other students": values[length-7]
}
browser.close()
print scores
```

That will output:

```
{'Lectures': u'2.71', 'Papers, Reports, Problem Sets, Examinations': u'3.31', 'Readings': u'3.67', 'Overall Quality of the Course': u'3.00', 'Feedback for other students': u'3.56', 'Precepts': u'3.43'}
```

Comment: AHHH yes it worked!!!!!!! I just needed to convert the map type into a list using

    lis = list(values)

Thanks a ton! Can't thank you enough!

Comment: Thanks a ton @pthamm

Answer (score 0):

Without more of the HTML it's hard to say what the right locator would be. I would start with the actual element that contains the text and avoid locators that use things like `nth-child()` because it's WAY too easy for the HTML to change slightly and then your locator is pointing at the wrong element.

The element you want is `<tspan dy="4">3.00</tspan>`. Have you tried a simple CSS selector like, `tspan[dy='4']`?

I'm hoping that the `dy` is related to the text position and will be unique on the page. If you can post the HTML for the entire row that contains the "Overall quality of the course" label and the bar graph that contains 3.00, I think that an XPath can be created to find what you want.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! 
Here is the HTML code for the "Lectures" element for example...I don't think the dy is unique to the rows :(

   ` <text style="text-anchor: middle; font: 12px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;" 
    x="0" y="0" text-anchor="middle" font="10px &quot;Arial&quot;" 
    stroke="none" fill="#3c4c30" font-size="12px" font-
    family="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif" font-style="normal" font-
    weight="normal" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,227,14.5833)"><tspan 
    dy="4">Lectures</tspan></text>`

Comment: And this is the HTML element for that specific row:

`<text style="text-anchor: middle; font: 12px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;" x="0" y="0" text-anchor="middle" font="10px &quot;Arial&quot;" stroke="none" fill="#3c4c30" font-size="12px" font-family="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,173.0333,131.25)"><tspan dy="4">Overall Quality of the Course</tspan></text>`

Comment: And the code for the bar graph with the 3.00:

`<rect x="262.03334045410156" y="125.17361111111111" width="195.7799955368042" height="12.152777777777777" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#ffffff" style="stroke-linejoin: round; stroke-linecap: square; stroke-opacity: 0; opacity: 1; fill-opacity: 0;" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-width="0" stroke-opacity="0" opacity="1" fill-opacity="0"></rect>`

Comment: Would it be possible to identify that row based on the x/y coordinates?

Comment: Find the nearest parent element that contains both the `text` and `rect` elements and post that entire block in your question formatted.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I added the rows above and below the one I am trying to target